# Is it a good idea to use the RDM socket type for multiplayer games?

Tags: c#, networking

I am currently developing a MOBA/RTS style game with an authoritative networking structure. Of course, the server needs to send a big number of packets every second, answering requests from the clients. The packets are split into commands and states. Commands contain all the actions a unit has performed since the last send-procedure, and states include the position and rotation data about a unit.
Commands are sent over TCP because they need to be in the right order and reliable for synchronized gameplay, individually to every client, states over UDP through a multicast group that consists out of the player clients because I interpolate, and a lost packet will not create any damage then.

Today i came across the RDM socket type, selectable through the C# Socket constructor, and I thought that this maybe is what I really want? My TCP connections currently do not make use of the seamless streaming of bytes as I wrap my data into packets and send them in constant intervalls. is the RDM socket type what I want? Having reliable connection-less packets send over PGM sounds really promising to me.

Comment: I've not heard of it. Which means you do not want it. Also UDP packets, you can put _your own_ note in them that tells the clients if one was missed, it seems like you've gotten the gist

Comment: That is true, but before reinventing the wheel I better ask.

Comment: When it comes to systems programming I'd say "yes, sure - consider it" but games. No. Build what you need.